# Can an Adobe AIR app be installed on a completely clean Windows system without the use of an install package?

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air

All of the documentation I have seen regarding distribution of Adobe AIR apps suggests that an installer is required to be run in order to get the runtime and the app onto a system.

The environment I am working in requires the AIR runtime, the AIR app and associated DLL's (it will be calling Windows native processes) to be transferred to a clean system and this needs to happen without running an install package. Ideally in the form of just copying the necessary files (DLL's, resources etc..) to where they need to be. Scripts can be used for tasks like adding registry keys and similar requirements. The build needs to be automated in the form of a copy, hence why no installer packages are suitable.

Does anyone know whether this is at all possible with Adobe AIR? Note, the app is Windows-only so cross platform is not a requirement.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If you can use a script, why can't you run a silent install? You can automate silent installs of AdobeAIR fairly easily. Check this out: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html lots of questions answered in the FAQ. Here's a document explaining all your distribution options with AIR: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/air_runtimeredist.pdf

Comment: That document is very helpful, thank you Jonathan. I didn't think that silent install would do what I wanted (e.g. bypass the EULA display) but it looks like it may. Can I build an AIR app which utilises native processes and install using the silent installer?

Comment: Yes you can use NativeProcess with a silently installed air install. There's no difference in the final product installed on the computer. And yes, EULA can be bypassed as well. To legally redistribute however, you do need to fill out a form on Adobe's website: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=distribution_form&pv=air

Comment: added more details in my answer addressing NativeProcess specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding more details in this answer.

In order to use NativeProcess your app must be an EXE compiled by ADT using "extended-desktop." I didn't find much documentation ont his, but a normal air app installs silently like this

```
C:\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe -silent -eulaAccepted "C:\yourApp.air"
```

Since the ADT compiled EXE already contains air, you can acutally just do this

```
C:\yourApp.EXE -silent -eulaAccepted -location "\"C:\WhereToInstall\""
```

I don't *believe* you need a redistributable license to do this... but I could be wrong. It's easy to get and free so you might as well.

Where yourAPP.EXE is the extended desktop AIR app compiled by ADT. For compiling an EXE by ADT see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll apply for the redist license to be on the safe side. Great comments, and a very helpful answer. Cheers!

Comment: I've packaged up a Native Installer using those instructions, but the silent install doesn't seem to be working. "Unable to download runtime installer without -allowDownload".  Any ideas? The system I am installing to does not have internet access, so no chance of downloading the runtime... but I thought it was already in the native installer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about the internet access restriction. There's a tool called "InstallJammer" which can include the runtime. Here's a tutorial: http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/deploying-air-application-with-air-runtimeredistributable-in-single-exe/ It's written for an earlier version of AIR but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, it turns out that on this last point it was a case of me being dense. I got the silent installs for both the AIR runtime, and the Native Installer working separately, so I can just install them one after the other using a batch file. You've been exceedingly helpful, once I get enough reputation to vote this answer up, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

No; this won't be possible.  You'll have to install the AIR Runtime on the Windows machine to run an AIR app.  And I expect the AIR app won't actually run w/o running the AIR App installer.

You may be able to look into alternate non-AIR options to turn SWFs into EXE. [Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/) is one such software to do that.

Or it is possible you can create an invisible installer.  I believe if you sign up for [redistribution of the AIR Runtime](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html) there is a way to make the runtime installer "invisible".  I'm not sure about the app, though.